# Javascript Conflict ajax mail and scriptaculous

Tags: javascript

I've added a javascript element I found in a guide. It is as follows

```
$(document).ready(function ()
    {
        $('.dropdownbutton').click(function ()
        {
        $.post("send.php", $(".mycontactform").serialize(),  function (data) 
            {   
            });
        $('#success').html('Message sent!');
        $('#success').hide(2000);
    });
});
```

The existing javascript was

```
        function toggleDisplayWait(divId, imgId, durationmSec) {
        if(!$(divId).visible()) {
            move = Effect.BlindDown;
            newImage = "./img/minus.png";
        }
        else {
            move = Effect.BlindUp;
            newImage = "./img/plus.png";  
        }        
        move(divId, {duration: durationmSec / 1000.0 });
        setTimeout(function() { $(imgId).src = newImage; }, durationmSec)
    }



function BDEffect(divId, imgId)
    {
        /* new Effect.BlindDown(element, {duration:3});
        }*/

        if(!$(divId).visible()) 
            {
                move = Effect.BlindDown;
                newImage = "./img/feedbacktab_open.png";
                setTimeout(function() { $(imgId).src = newImage; }, 0)
            }
        else 
            {
                move = Effect.BlindUp;
                newImage = "./img/feedbacktab.png";
                setTimeout(function() { $(imgId).src = newImage; }, 2)
            }        
            move(divId, {duration:2});
            /*setTimeout(function() { $(imgId).src = newImage; }, 0)*/
    }
</script>
```

But neither the OLD code nor the NEW code works now.

Error console now reporting "$(divId).visible is not a function" when i try to use the old script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The old code looks like it's using the Prototype framework, and the new code is using jQuery.

When you use the two together, you need to use jQuery's `noConflict()` so that they don't both try to use the `$` variable.

First, after including the jQuery library, add a script like this:

```
<script>
  jQuery.noConflict()
</script>
```

Then modify your jQuery code to look like this:

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $('.dropdownbutton').click(function() {
    $.post("send.php", $(".mycontactform").serialize(), function(data) {});
    $('#success').html('Message sent!');
    $('#success').hide(2000);
});
```

With `noConflict`, everywhere you want to use jQuery, you must use the `jQuery` variable instead of `$`. However, you can still pass `$` in as a local variable, and it will not conflict with Prototype.

Also, note that I changed your `document.ready(function() { ... })` function into [jQuery's shorthand version](http://api.jquery.com/ready/): `jQuery(function() { ... })`. The function will also get passed the `jQuery` object, which I name `$` for convenience.

Comment: Worked nicely! Send button doesn't seem to do anything though, guess thats my next problem!